# JOOQ Timestamp precision on query

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jooq

I have this raw query for PSQL that I would like to transform to JOOQ query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('day', ref_date) AS refdate
FROM income
WHERE probos_id = :probosId
```

The best version I was able to create is:

```
Result<Record1<Timestamp>> result = createQueryBuilder()
    .selectDistinct(incomeTable.REF_DATE.cast(Date.class).cast(Timestamp.class).as("refdate"))
    .from(incomeTable)
    .where(incomeTable.PROBOS_ID.eq(probosId))
    .fetch();
```

This is the generated query:

```
select distinct 
cast(cast("public"."income"."ref_date" as date) as timestamp) as "refdate" 
from "public"."income"
where "public"."income"."probos_id" = ?
```

I'd like to find a better way for set the precision (like date_trunc in PSQL) to get the necessary value without doulbe casting.

If it's possible I'd like to find a native solution without extending the DSL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DSL.trunc(Field, DatePart)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#trunc-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.DatePart-), i.e.

```
Result<Record1<Timestamp>> result = createQueryBuilder()
    .selectDistinct(trunc(incomeTable.REF_DATE, DatePart.DAY).as("refdate"))
    .from(incomeTable)
    .where(incomeTable.PROBOS_ID.eq(probosId))
    .fetch();
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't find it in the doc. One more question: how can I orderBy with this new "as("refdate")" field?

Comment: @KrizsánBalazs: I'll be very happy to answer a new stack overflow question