# JOOQ orderBy() from trunc()-ed field

Tags: java, sql, database, query-builder, jooq

Based on this question: [JOOQ Timestamp precision on query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681406/jooq-timestamp-precision-on-query/51683265)

This is the query that I have:

```
    Result<Record1<Timestamp>> result = createQueryBuilder()
        .selectDistinct(trunc(incomeTable.REF_DATE, DatePart.DAY).as("refdate"))
        .from(incomeTable)
        .where(incomeTable.PROBOS_ID.eq(probosId))
        .fetch();
```

I would like to add an `.orderBy()` to the where by the `as("refdate")` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, the easiest one will be to assign your projected column expression to a local variable and reuse it twice in the query

```java
Field<Timestamp> refdate = trunc(incomeTable.REF_DATE, DatePart.DAY).as("refdate");

Result<Record1<Timestamp>> result = createQueryBuilder()
    .selectDistinct(refdate)
    .from(incomeTable)
    .where(incomeTable.PROBOS_ID.eq(probosId))
    .orderBy(refdate)
    .fetch();
```

Or, if that's not possible, create a new field reference for the order by clause using [`DSL.field(Name)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Name-):

```java
Result<Record1<Timestamp>> result = createQueryBuilder()
    .selectDistinct(trunc(incomeTable.REF_DATE, DatePart.DAY).as("refdate"))
    .from(incomeTable)
    .where(incomeTable.PROBOS_ID.eq(probosId))
    .orderBy(field(name("refdate"))
    .fetch();
```